# What is the optimal way to train neural networks on Amazon Web Services for training neural networks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, keras, convolution

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I can't solve my problem.

I have a dataset contains a lot of images divided on classes (like [this](https://challenge.kitware.com/#challenge/n/ISIC_2017%3A_Skin_Lesion_Analysis_Towards_Melanoma_Detection) or [this](https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection/data)). The size of the data is more than 5 Gb.
I need to train the deep convolution neural network (e.g. [Inception](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Szegedy_Going_Deeper_With_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf)).

Training of such a network requires a huge amount of computing resources that are not available in my computer. So, I decided to train it on Amazon GPU instance. I've made an instance like in [this nice tutorial](http://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-evaluate-large-deep-learning-models-keras-amazon-web-services/). I connected it through WinSCP (explained [here](http://docs.rightscale.com/faq/How_to_Transfer_Files_from_EC2_to_Desktop_Using_WinSCP.html)). But I have a problem associated with uploading the data on my instance EBS volume. When I try to do this whith WinSCP it takes a lot of time (more than 10 hours). The speed of my internet connection is 10 Mb/sec, but the speed of uploading files on ec2 is 50-60 Kb/sec. I have no idea, why.

Could you suggest the best way to solve my problem? For example, is it possible to create a disc without running instance, upload data to it and then attach it to the instance? If so, advise links to tutorials.

The instance is Ubuntu, my operation system is Windows 10.

Many thanks!

Comment: Sounds like what you're asking is "how can I shift >5GB data to AWS quickly?" Main factor here is your internet connection not the way you configure AWS.

Comment: I don't know why, but the speed of uploading files on ec2 instance very low. the speed of my internet connection is 10 Mb, but the speed of uploading files on ec2 is 50-60 Kb/sec (((

Comment: Make sure you are uploading to a region close to you. I noticed that AWS uploads start slow and increase in speed. I'd recommend that you use AWS CLI tools for maximum performance. Also, you might want to send it to S3 and not to your instance.